# For (VBA) When I Insert Rows/Columns manually, how do I make it automatically change it on my code

Tags: vba

Lets say I have x = Range("B1").value
I insert a row and the value of B1 moves to C1 
B1 is blank, so now i have x = something else.

Is there a way to move all the cells on the code if I add a row or column?

*Edit
I'm a beginner and im just using vba to make my own personal budget. And because Im a beginner I didn't quite write what should be added and such, so im adding new things to it which requires me adding more rows or cells.

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj0DH.png)

[Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03AcS.png)

Comment: name the range would do it range("interesting_data_1").value

Comment: Named ranges would shift with the addition/deletion of a row or column but that solution may be unwieldy if you had a large number to track. Add some scope to your question and provide more detail on the reasoning behind the hard-coded cell addresses. There are all sorts of dynamic lookup methods; chosing the right one requires more information.

Answer (score 0):

The INDIRECT function returns a reference to a range. You can use this function to create a reference that won't change if row or columns are inserted in the worksheet. Or, use it to create a reference from letters and numbers in other cells.

You can learn more about it here.

http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html